# PHP Curl - Correct URL Parameters

Tags: php, curl

I just played with PHP Curl for the first time and wrote a sample code, but I don't know how to pass the parameters in the URL correctly.

**Remote Site Code:**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['updateme']))
{

$license = $Gauntlet->filter($_REQUEST['licensekey']); 
$domainnew = $Gauntlet->filter($_REQUEST['domainnew']);
$domainold = strtolower($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


$sqlcheckexist = "SELECT * FROM licenses WHERE licensekey = '$license' AND host = '$domainold' AND status = 'active'";
$querycheck = $DatabaseHandler->query($sqlcheckexist);

if($querycheck)
{

if($querycheck->num_rows < 1){

   $json['status'] = 301;
   $json['message'] = 'Wrong Domain or License'; 
}else{
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE licenses SET host = '$domainnew', status = 'active' WHERE licensekey = '$license'";

$json['message'] = 'Success!'; 

}
}
}
```

Remote Site API Url: `mydomain.com/myapi/`

How can i do this `REQUEST` in Url with parameters if i `POST` `licensekey` and `domainnew` and `Update` my Database value?

Comment: Hi, becarfull you have a lot of SQLinjection in your code take a look here : https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection and use Prepare request in PHP

Comment: Thanks for the Info, i just learning:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post value using php curl like this

```
      $payload=array();
      $payload['licensekey']='abc';
      $payload['domainnew']='123';
      $payload['updateme']='update';

      $payload=json_encode($payload);

      $ch = curl_init($url); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $res=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: And in browser URL like: `mydomain.com/myapi/?` for testing?

Comment: If you want to send values with url using curl. 
`$ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http:/mydomain.com/myapi/?licensekey=1111&domainnew=222&updateme=1');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);`